# JavaScript QuerySelector failed

Tags: javascript, queryselector

anyone have a idea why the querySelector wont work ?

```js
var itemID ="8zoncALaudovCbLRYGbx";

console.log(document.getElementById(itemID)); //work
console.log(document.querySelector("."+itemID)); //not work why ? (error :"not a valid selector")
console.log(document.querySelector("#"+itemID)); // not work why ? (error :"not a valid selector")
```

```html
<div class="8zoncALaudovCbLRYGbx" id="8zoncALaudovCbLRYGbx">useless text</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect that to do?

Comment: i want to get the div with a classname or idname (8zoncALaudovCbLRYGbx) via query selector

Comment: You have no DIV with that class name. You're not doing anything with the result of `document.querySelector(\`#${itemID}\`);`.

Comment: And you forgot the `$` inside the `innerHTML` template literal.

Comment: I just want to know why the querySelector doesn't found the div

thank you for your patience :)

Comment: How are you loading your JavaScript into the html, is it via script src attribute or script element

Comment: after the body(bottom of the page ) and with <script src>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function

```
   function EditModal(itemID) {
  const mod = document.querySelector(".edit-modal");
  document.body.style = "overflow:hidden; position :absolute;height:100%";

  const test = document.getElementById(itemID);
  console.log(document.querySelector('div[id="'+`${itemID}`+'"]'));

  mod.innerHTML = `"$⏪for testing"{document.querySelector("div."+itemID+",.title")}`;
}
```

Comment: same problem he didn't found the div element  " not a valid selector"

Comment: I edited answer check it

Comment: sorry but it still doesn't work
I think that querySelector doesn't like my itemID because it works until I add it
it comes from an unacceptable character or that it is too long?

Comment: you can try at home I can't get this type of id to work (8zoncALaudovCbLRYGbx) with queryselector it is unable to find it even if I define it as a class
I think I tested all the possible ways to write it
it works for all the rest except for this type of text (itemID)